# Achievement System CRUD data structure

Tags: design, data-structures

I'm developing this Achievement System and it must have a CRUD, that admins access to create new achievements and it's rules. I need some help with the Achievement CRUD data structure.

#### Rules sample

**Medal one**: must complete 5 any courses with a score of at least 90
**Medal two**: must complete two specific courses with a score of at least 85
**Medal three**: must be top 5 in general ranking at least once
**Medal four**: must have more than 5000 points

I'll store that in a SQL database and thought about two options.

#### Option A

Create a table with a few columns like below to store those multiple variables when suited:

- action
- action quantity
- course quantity
- score
- id course
- ranking
  position
- points

#### Option B

Store that using JSON or serialized format, so all the logic of parsing that is inside my code, downside is it will make it more complex to query some rules (not sure i'll need to query it, but I like to be ready just in case).

Bear in mind there is a high chance that I'll have to add more rules to this system, that's why I'm asking this.

Is there a more suitable way of doing that, perhaps a design pattern, a known solution or something already created for this scenario?

Comment: @DocBrown there is a high chance that I'll have to add more rules to this system, that's why I'm looking for any known solution to this scenario. I only thought about those two options, but I don't favor any of them, just want to know the best way.

Comment: This whole dynamic rule system sounds like a lot of work for something that would be fairly trivial in code. You say there’s a chance you’ll need to add more rules later, why don’t you think of those additional rules now? And if you really can’t what prevents you from updating your application later to add more rules?

Comment: @RikD that's how things are in my work right now, things just pop up in the future. I was just wondering if there is a known solution to this kind of problem that make it easy to add rules, if not, I'll just stick to Option A.

Comment: The thing is that a system like this might look dynamic, but when the business comes up with crazy new ideas for achievements it really isn’t. What about an achievement for completing a course within a certain time period?

Comment: @RikD That achievement is likely to be asked in the future.

Comment: Databases (regardless of format) are about storing state. Code is about storing rules about how that state is used (regardless of what you call it - business logic, domain logic, etc.). Trying to store rules in a database is quite painful. I've done it before. I will not do it again. Rather, than focusing on the data structure for the rules, I would focus on the class structure.

Comment: @DocBrown if I store in JSON, when there's a new rule I won't have to create another column in DB, I'll just implement that logic in the code. Anyway... The problem I'm really trying to solve here now is the design / algorithm to make it easy to add new rules in the future.

Comment: @DocBrown those are the parameters, so one person should complete any 5 courses to get that achievement. There's another table I didn't mention which is like a log, that registers each user action and it's quantity so I can know when one has achieved something. These logged actions are just those involved in any achievement.

Answer (score 1):

There are two general approaches here, for which you have to clarify the requirements first:

1. Only support a restricted set of predefined rules or rule types. If the rule types need to be extended, some other programmer has to extend the system by adding code and deploying a new version.
2. Support almost arbitrary rules, and users can extend them by themselves.

I guess this is what you roughly have in mind with your options A and B - but I hope my description makes it more clear that this is not a question of "design patterns" - it is simply a question of the requirement "**Who shall be able to extend the rules?**".

So given you really need a system where users can extend the rules by themselves, then you could store them as pairs of "boolean expression" and "reward". The boolean expression would be some formula with some predefined functions as building blocks, logical operators "and", "or", "not", and comparison operators, used like

```
  $NoOfCoursesAboveLimit(90) >=5 

  $ScoreOfCourse("X")>85 and $ScoreOfCourse("Y")>85

  $RankingPosition()<=5

  $TotalScore()>=5000
```

So no fancy "JSON" or "serialization format" involved, just a subset or modification of your favorite programming language, something as user-friend as formulas can be.

Of course, this approach needs probably more effort to be implemented than the first one. One needs to define a grammar, then implement a parser and finally an expression evaluator together with the logic for those predefined functions.

Fortunately, this is not a new problem. For the described case something like the [Shunting-yard algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm) should be sufficient for the parsing. The final evaluation step is then just traversing the abstract syntax tree created by the parser.

Comment: Thinking about it, letting all the decision to create new rules to users is dangerous, the development team should validate that first, so I choose approach number 1, but still all you said has big value to me, thank you very much!

Comment: @EdsonHoracioJunior: is it so dangerous? Ordinary users do this all the times, using spreadsheets like Excel.

Comment: I expressed myself wrong, I meant that I don't want users creating new "types"  of rules (with new parameters that didn't exist before), but they may create new rules using the ones that already exist.

Comment: @EdsonHoracioJunior: even in approach #2, users can only use the basic functions you provide to them, like `$NoOfCoursesAboveLimit` or `$ScoreOfCourse`. However, they can combine them in more flexible ways than in approach #1.